# Dynamic template arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, dynamic

I want a template class to contain two template dynamic arrays as member variables. I use also a member function to assign to them values. However I got problem with the code and I do not know the reason (probably the syntax). What is the problem in the following code?

```
template<typename T>
class ArrayHolder
 {
public:
ArrayHolder();
void setArrays( T [], T [],int,int);


private:
T *array1;
T *array2;
};


template<typename T>
ArrayHolderHolder<T>::setArrays(T firstarray[],T secondarray[] ,int N1, int N2)
{
array1 = new T[N1];
array2 = new T[N2];


}
```

After the initialization of the dynamic arrays in setArrays, what is the most effective to copy the arrays from the parameters (firstarray,secondarray) to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayHolderHolder<T>::setArrays(T firstarray[],T secondarray[] ,int N1, int N2)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here is one typo. The class name is `ArrayHolder`, not`ArrayHolderHolder`. Also, you didn't write the *return type*.

Since you cannot pass array (by value), it is better if you use pointer notation function in parameter list, and since it is class template, prefer defining the functions in the class itself:

```
template<typename T>
class ArrayHolder
{
  public:
     ArrayHolder();

     void setArrays(T *firstarray,T *secondarray ,int N1, int N2)
     {
        array1 = new T[N1];
        array2 = new T[N2];

        //if you want to copy, then use `std::copy` as:
        std::copy(firstarray, firstarray + N1, array1);
        std::copy(secondarray, secondarray + N2, array2);
     }

private:
   T *array1;
   T *array2;
};
```

By the way, instead of raw arrays, you could use `st::vector` as:

```
std::vector<T> array1;
std::vector<T> array2;
```

And same in the parameter list of `setArrays` as well. If you do so, then `setArray` would become this:

```
void setArrays(const std::vector<T> & first, const std::vector<T> & second)
{
    //maybe you need to do this!
    array1.clear();
    array2.clear();

    array1.insert(array1.end(), first.begin(), first.end());
    array2.insert(array2.end(), second.begin(), second.end());
}
```

Simple, isn't it? No memory allocation, no deallocation!

Or even better, if you accept the arguments by value, then you could write this:

```
void setArrays(std::vector<T> first, std::vector<T> second)
{
    //no need to clear!
    array1.swap(first);
    array2.swap(second);
}
```

The last implementation is an idiomatic solution, preferred by library implementers.

Comment: The first typo comes only from paste fault, it is correct written in the actual code (still my mistake). The approach with the vector is familiar to me but I wanted to try with a dynamic array as well. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Everythyng is fine, just one remark. In C++11 you can now use the following syntax:
std::copy( std::begin(array), std::end(array), std::begin(dst) );
It works both for vectors and simple arrays.

Comment: @Werolik: The third parameter of `std::copy` shouldn't be `std::begin(dst)`. It will not work for `std::vector`. If you want to use that, then you've to do this before : `dst.resize(array.size())`.

Comment: @Nawaz: You are right. `resize` should be used before, or push-back-inserter as dst iterator.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Nawaz answer: you forgot `void` return type before setArrays() definition.

Comment: You are right, that caused the error finally. I am not yet good at detecting and identifying the problems, since the compiler messages are not quite explicit.

Answer (score 0):

std::copy is the most effective way.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/

```
std::copy(firstarray, firstarray + N1, array1);
std::copy(secondarray, secondarray + N2, array2);
```

Of course, this is only if you insist on using arrays. Personally I always use a container from the standard template library. In this case I would use a std::vector but to each their own.