# Get the length of dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

Continuing from the linked question [Dynamic template arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366505/dynamic-template-arrays), there two more things that I would like to be explained:

1. I receive a warning by the compiler that the copy commands are unsafe: “Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct”
   How serious is this problem and what can be done to get over it?
2. Most important: 
   I cannot get correctly the length of the array with the common manner. The final size of array is calculated to 1, although it contains 3 elements. Is there a flaw in the code or something works differently due to dynamic arrays?

Here is my code:

```
template<typename T>
void VectorHolder<T>::setArrays(T firstarray[],T secondarray[] ,int N1, int N2)
{

    array1 = new T[N1];
    array2 = new T[N2];

    std::copy(firstarray, firstarray + N1, array1);
    std::copy(secondarray, secondarray + N2, array2);

    int arraysize = sizeof(array1)/sizeof(T);

    cout<<"\narraysize: "<<arraysize<<endl;
    cout<<"\nFirst array contains: \n";

    for(int i=0; i<arraysize;i++)
        cout<<array1[i]<<endl;
}
```

I get at the output only one element, but the array contains three. If I change the for loop as

```
for(int i=0; i<N1;i++)
```

I get the correct result. Why?

Comment: Post the warning messages as well.

Comment: Why do you need to calculate array size when N1 and N2 are passed in?

Comment: Anyway, in the other topic, I suggested you to use `std::vector<T>` instead of `T[]`, but you didn't listen to me. So explain, is there any problem in using `std::vector`? Because I don't see you would get better solution than that.

Comment: Why do you use raw pointers instead of stl containers?? You could use std::vector in this case.

Comment: Pseudo-rule: In C++, don't use naked arrays and don't use `new` (unless in controlled conditions), and `delete` never..

Comment: @KerrekSB, `new` only for runtime polymorphism; `new[]`, `delete` and `delete[]` never.

Comment: @avakar: Personally, I'd say `new` and `new[]` only inside `unique_ptr` constructors, and otherwise never; though there's always the possibility that you have your own memory-managing class. But in that case you'd understand enough to know when to break the rule! :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB, I completely agree with the `unique_ptr` rule. I have to disagree with `new[]`, one has no business using it when one has `vector` available. :)

Comment: @avakar: Sometimes a `unique_ptr<T[]>` suffices, and you don't need a full `vector<T>`; so then you need the array-new. But I agree, such situations ought to be rare.

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider using `std::vector` and its [size](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/size/) method?

Comment: I suggested him to use that in the other topic as well. I explained the usage as well.

Comment: Ok guys, of course I prefer vectors and I know that are more easily conceivable. I just tried smth with dynamic arrays to gain some knowledge about them. It is an experimental attempt, not a real project.

Answer (score 2):

`array1` is not an array, it's a pointer.  Therefore, its size is that of a pointer, and is constant.

Consider using a standard container rather than a raw C-style array.

Answer (score 2):

### Question 1:

Don't mind much about that warning. It warns you about a risk of an overflow.
To get rid of it, and if you're using Visual Studio, add this to your file :

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4996 )
```

I assume 4996 is the code of this warning.

### Question 2:

The fact that you have :

```
array1 = new T[N1];
```

means that **array1** is a pointer on T:

```
T * array1;
```

Let's suppose N2 is much bigger than N1, **although that** you will find that **sizeof(array1) is equal to sizeof(array2)**.

I guess this due to the fact that sizeof(array1) returns the memory allocated for the pointer itself and not to the value to which the pointer points to, but not sure of this~.

**A simple test :**

```
char * tab1;
tab1 = new char[3];

char * tab2;
tab2 = new char[100];

if( sizeof(tab1) == sizeof(tab2) )
{
    printf("equals");
}
```

will return : "equals"

**To resolve this problem try this** :

```
std::vector<T> array1;
```

and consider getting the size by :

```
array1.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you *really* want to use dynamic arrays, then do it properly:
never use `[]`, but always only pointers. Most annoyingly, you **MUST** pass the size of the array separately **and** take care to `delete` your array. Both these issues are tricky in complicated programs and using containers that take care of them is much preferred.